Unable to Retrieve All Webinars, But Can Fetch Single Webinar by ID
I'm working on a project where I need to use the Microsoft Graph API to fetch a list of webinars and display them in our front-end application. However, I've encountered an issue that I can't seem to resolve.
**The Problem:
**I am trying to retrieve all webinars using the following API endpoint:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/virtualEvents/webinars
Despite having granted the necessary permissions (as shown in the screenshot), the API keeps returning an access denied error when trying to fetch all webinars. However, when I attempt to get the details of a single webinar by its ID, it works perfectly fine. This behavior is very confusing.

What I've Tried:

I've double-checked the permissions in Azure AD and ensured that I have the necessary scopes (screenshots attached).
I've refreshed the Graph Explorer page multiple times.
I’ve tried re-granting the permissions 2-3 times to ensure everything is correct.
None of these steps have resolved the issue.

Screenshots:
Proof of granted permissions but failing to fetch all webinars: 
Successful fetch of a single webinar by ID: 
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there something I'm missing in terms of permissions or API usage?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
For the update, If I try with application permission then I get the data count but I am not getting the webinars list is coming empty all the time.

I already tried to remove the $count from the filter part the also list is coming empty([]), And here is the proof that I have the webinar on my list 
Thanks in advance!

The endpoint GET /solutions/virtualEvents/webinars doesn't support delegated permissions, only application permissions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/virtualeventsroot-list-webinars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Yes, you are correct but still, If I try with application permission I am getting webinar count but not the webinars it's coming [] you can check my question again.
Thanks for your help

ok, it leads to another issue. I will check on my side
